# rq() delivers the same coefficient results for all tau

Tags: r, cross-validation, quantile-regression

I created a large module (52 covariates mostly factors), to estimate the effect of compulsory schooling on log_earnings. I used the quantile regresion technique. Since I do my study in R I go with a gender-specfic quantile regression formula that follows :

```
fit <- rq(log_hourly_earnings ~ 1 + edu_years  + ycomp + country_name_Austria + country_name_Belgium +  country_name_Denmark + country_name_Germany + country_name_Greece +
     country_name_Italy + country_name_Netherlands + country_name_Spain + country_name_Sweden + q + q_2 +
     q:country_name_Austria + q:country_name_Belgium +  q:country_name_Denmark + q:country_name_Germany + q:country_name_Greece +
     q:country_name_Italy + q:country_name_Netherlands + q:country_name_Spain + q:country_name_Sweden +
     q_2:country_name_Austria + q_2:country_name_Belgium +  q_2:country_name_Denmark + q_2:country_name_Germany + q_2:country_name_Greece +
     q_2:country_name_Italy + q_2:country_name_Netherlands + q_2:country_name_Spain + q_2:country_name_Sweden+ age + age_2 + age:country_name_Austria + age:country_name_Belgium +  age:country_name_Denmark + age:country_name_Germany + age:country_name_Greece +
       age:country_name_Italy + age:country_name_Netherlands + age:country_name_Spain + age:country_name_Sweden +
       age_2:country_name_Austria + age_2:country_name_Belgium +  age_2:country_name_Denmark + age_2:country_name_Germany + age_2:country_name_Greece +
       age_2:country_name_Italy + age_2:country_name_Netherlands + age_2:country_name_Spain + age_2:country_name_Sweden ,
data =  dataset %>% filter(gender == 0), tau = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9), method = 'sfn')
```

Surprisingly all coefficients for all tau are the same for each gender. Can someone explain me how this could have happend? Could be singularity a problem here, since R throws a warning when I run the regression? If so, is a lasso cross-validation of the covariates a possible solution to this?

Output of the covarites

```
  tau= 0.1       tau= 0.3       tau= 0.5       tau= 0.7       tau= 0.9
 [1,]   1.639825e+00   1.639825e+00   1.639825e+00   1.639825e+00   1.639825e+00
 [2,]   1.523253e-02   1.523253e-02   1.523253e-02   1.523253e-02   1.523253e-02
 [3,]   3.716469e-02   3.716469e-02   3.716469e-02   3.716469e-02   3.716469e-02
 [4,]  -5.180479e+00  -5.180479e+00  -5.180479e+00  -5.180479e+00  -5.180479e+00
 [5,]  -1.014919e+00  -1.014919e+00  -1.014919e+00  -1.014919e+00  -1.014919e+00
 [6,]   2.893649e+01   2.893649e+01   2.893649e+01   2.893649e+01   2.893649e+01
 [7,]   2.722460e+01   2.722460e+01   2.722460e+01   2.722460e+01   2.722460e+01
 [8,]   1.616250e+01   1.616250e+01   1.616250e+01   1.616250e+01   1.616250e+01
 [9,]  -3.765513e+01  -3.765513e+01  -3.765513e+01  -3.765513e+01  -3.765513e+01
[10,]   4.897362e+00   4.897362e+00   4.897362e+00   4.897362e+00   4.897362e+00
[11,]  -2.971778e+01  -2.971778e+01  -2.971778e+01  -2.971778e+01  -2.971778e+01
[12,]  -1.937196e+02  -1.937196e+02  -1.937196e+02  -1.937196e+02  -1.937196e+02
[13,]  -5.479048e-03  -5.479048e-03  -5.479048e-03  -5.479048e-03  -5.479048e-03
[14,]  -1.124863e-03  -1.124863e-03  -1.124863e-03  -1.124863e-03  -1.124863e-03
[15,]  9.650725e-138  9.650725e-138  9.650725e-138  9.650725e-138  9.650725e-138
[16,]  2.826744e-136  2.826744e-136  2.826744e-136  2.826744e-136  2.826744e-136
[17,]   5.695895e-02   5.695895e-02   5.695895e-02   5.695895e-02   5.695895e-02
[18,]   1.376220e-01   1.376220e-01   1.376220e-01   1.376220e-01   1.376220e-01
[19,]  -1.046340e+00  -1.046340e+00  -1.046340e+00  -1.046340e+00  -1.046340e+00
[20,]  -8.650425e-01  -8.650425e-01  -8.650425e-01  -8.650425e-01  -8.650425e-01
[21,]  -4.058974e-01  -4.058974e-01  -4.058974e-01  -4.058974e-01  -4.058974e-01
[22,]   1.000750e+00   1.000750e+00   1.000750e+00   1.000750e+00   1.000750e+00
[23,]  -1.894731e-01  -1.894731e-01  -1.894731e-01  -1.894731e-01  -1.894731e-01
[24,]   6.248212e-01   6.248212e-01   6.248212e-01   6.248212e-01   6.248212e-01
[25,]   6.002442e+00   6.002442e+00   6.002442e+00   6.002442e+00   6.002442e+00
[26,]  3.524412e-138  3.524412e-138  3.524412e-138  3.524412e-138  3.524412e-138
[27,] -2.312222e-137 -2.312222e-137 -2.312222e-137 -2.312222e-137 -2.312222e-137
[28,]   1.123495e-02   1.123495e-02   1.123495e-02   1.123495e-02   1.123495e-02
[29,]   7.777675e-03   7.777675e-03   7.777675e-03   7.777675e-03   7.777675e-03
[30,]  5.094586e-138  5.094586e-138  5.094586e-138  5.094586e-138  5.094586e-138
[31,] -8.766791e-138 -8.766791e-138 -8.766791e-138 -8.766791e-138 -8.766791e-138
[32,]   3.652023e-03   3.652023e-03   3.652023e-03   3.652023e-03   3.652023e-03
[33,] -2.208413e-137 -2.208413e-137 -2.208413e-137 -2.208413e-137 -2.208413e-137
[34,]  -4.345125e-02  -4.345125e-02  -4.345125e-02  -4.345125e-02  -4.345125e-02
[35,] -2.736136e-140 -2.736136e-140 -2.736136e-140 -2.736136e-140 -2.736136e-140
[36,]  -8.418559e-02  -8.418559e-02  -8.418559e-02  -8.418559e-02  -8.418559e-02
[37,] -2.109282e-139 -2.109282e-139 -2.109282e-139 -2.109282e-139 -2.109282e-139
[38,] -2.552147e-139 -2.552147e-139 -2.552147e-139 -2.552147e-139 -2.552147e-139
[39,]  -2.329413e-01  -2.329413e-01  -2.329413e-01  -2.329413e-01  -2.329413e-01
[40,]   1.167344e-01   1.167344e-01   1.167344e-01   1.167344e-01   1.167344e-01
[41,] -6.804289e-139 -6.804289e-139 -6.804289e-139 -6.804289e-139 -6.804289e-139
[42,]   2.491100e-01   2.491100e-01   2.491100e-01   2.491100e-01   2.491100e-01
[43,]  5.399369e-138  5.399369e-138  5.399369e-138  5.399369e-138  5.399369e-138
[44,]   1.214409e-03   1.214409e-03   1.214409e-03   1.214409e-03   1.214409e-03
[45,]   2.436206e-03   2.436206e-03   2.436206e-03   2.436206e-03   2.436206e-03
[46,]  -9.709977e-03  -9.709977e-03  -9.709977e-03  -9.709977e-03  -9.709977e-03
[47,]  -6.825626e-03  -6.825626e-03  -6.825626e-03  -6.825626e-03  -6.825626e-03
[48,]  -1.523064e-03  -1.523064e-03  -1.523064e-03  -1.523064e-03  -1.523064e-03
[49,]   7.935154e-03   7.935154e-03   7.935154e-03   7.935154e-03   7.935154e-03
[50,]  -1.736471e-03  -1.736471e-03  -1.736471e-03  -1.736471e-03  -1.736471e-03
[51,]   3.222036e-03   3.222036e-03   3.222036e-03   3.222036e-03   3.222036e-03
[52,]   4.747272e-02   4.747272e-02   4.747272e-02   4.747272e-02   4.747272e-02
```

Comment: How big is your sample size? It may be related to the sample size issue since you have a big number of predictors.

Comment: As my answear suggests, lasso solved the problem. Therefore indeed, the problem was probably due to a large number of covariates in comparison to roughly 8.000 observations

Comment: I'm curious why though. And it's not because coefficients changed with lasso that you solved the problem. A sample of 8000 is fairly large so that doesnt explain why the coefficients are the same. This is really odd.

Comment: If you have an idea how the problem can be solved without Lasso, feel free to help. If you need any more information (code, data) I can upload some things for you.

Comment: I expect that you didn't come up with an idea for a solution of this problem or?

Answer (score 2):

After I reduced the model to covariates given by the `LASSO.fit` the results differ for each tau and gender respectively.

My code to do so is the following :

```
X <- dataset  %>% .[,31:81] %>%
     mutate(gdp_head = dataset %>% .$gdp_head) %>%
     mutate(gdp_head_t_1 = dataset %>%  .$gdp_head_t_1) %>%
     mutate(gdp_head_t_2 = dataset %>% .$gdp_head_t_2)  %>%
     mutate(ycomp = dataset %>% .$ycomp) %>%
     mutate(edu_years = dataset%>% .$edu_years) %>%as.matrix() 

rq1 = LASSO.fit(dataset$log_hourly_earnings, X, tau = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9), intercept = T, lambda = 1, coef.cutoff=1e-08)
```

Afterwards, one just needs to reduce the formula given in `rq()`